# getdate() returns empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, debian

I have php5 on Debian 6.0.10 Squeeze. In one of my WordPress templates I am using the code shown below:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );
$today = getdate();
echo $today;
```

Only an empty array is echoed. Any suggestions on what I might be missing here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getdate()` returns an `Array` not a `String`.

Check the manual here :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

You should do this instead :

```
<?php
print_r($today);
?>
```

If you want UNIX timestamp then you can use `time()` function.

Or, if you want to have custom formatted date then you can use `date()` function

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
print_r($today);
```

OR

```
var_dump($today);
```

Instead of using echo use print_r() or var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` returns an array of following type:

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 40
    [minutes] => 58
    [hours]   => 21
    [mday]    => 17
    [wday]    => 2
    [mon]     => 6
    [year]    => 2003
    [yday]    => 167
    [weekday] => Tuesday
    [month]   => June
    [0]       => 1055901520
)
```

You can read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );
print_r(getdate());
```

Since getdate() doesn't return a string, you want to use print_r().